# if there have a package that provide a array with max length in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a package in nodejs.
It can provide a array-like struct with max length.
When you push a new data into that, it will auto delete the oldest data and add new data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't like how the question is written, but I like the idea :)

```
function FixedSizeArray(size) {
  var mySize = size;
  var array = new Array();

  return {
    push: function(obj) {
      if (array.length >= mySize)
        array.pop();

      array.push(obj)
    },
    getAt: function(idx) {
      return array[idx];
    }
  }
}
```

So, you can use it like:

```
var arrayMax10 = FixedSizeArray(10);
arrayMax10.push('thing');
...
arrayMax10.push('something');

arrayMax10.getAt(/*0..9*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's commonly called First Input First Output array, and with a fixed size and of course, there is a NPM library for it. Check it out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fifo-array

> fifo-array  A fixed-length, first-in-first-out array.

```
var FifoArray = require('fifo-array');

var fifoArray = new FifoArray(3, [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]);
console.log(fifoArray); // => [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ] 
console.log('max:', fifoArray.max); // => max: 3 
fifoArray.push(1, 2);
console.log(fifoArray); // => [ 'd', 1, 2 ]
```